# LoadLibraryA and relative path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I'm trying to load a dll (through LoadLibraryA) from another dll.
This is the problem:

```
c:\**EXE_DIR**\myExe.exe             // this exe load the MY_DLL_N1.dll
c:\**DLLS_DIR**\MY_DLL_N1.dll    // this dll load the MY_DLL_N2.dll
c:\**DLLS_DIR**\MY_DLL_N2.dll
```

1. the exe load the MY_DLL_N1.dll ... fine.
2. MY_DLL_N1.dll try to load (below the code) the MY_DLL_N2.dll (same dir) ... and here is my problem!

```
int LoadMyDLL()
{
    // ...

    // same path of the MY_DLL_N1.dll ... right?
    handle = LoadLibraryA ("MY_DLL_N2.dll");

    // ...
}
```

that's all .... any help is welcome!

Comment: You are asking for DLL Hell by expecting Windows to find the right DLL for you.  And you got it.  Windows doesn't want to solve this problem, intentionally.  Storing the DLLs in the same directory as the EXE should always be the first choice.  Intentionally putting them somewhere else to get another program to use the same DLLs is the worst kind of DLL Hell.  You'll update a DLL to fix a bug in one program.  And induce a bug in the other program.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handle = LoadLibraryA ("MY_DLL_N2.dll");
```

Because you do not supply a path, the [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) is used. This will look in the executable's directory, but will not search in the directories of any DLLS that are loaded. Hence the failure to find the DLL.

You have a number of options:

1. Put all the DLLS in the same directory as the executable.
2. Pass the full path to the DLL when calling LoadLibrary.
3. Call [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx) to add the DLL directory to the search path. Make this call from the executable before loading the first DLL. Once you do this you won't need to use the full path when loading the first DLL.

Unless you have a need to share the DLLS between different applications, option 1 is always preferred. This makes it easy for you to be sure that the DLLs you load are the right ones. That's because the executable directory is always searched first.

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need to know is located here: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications).

Consider using [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add your DLL path to the LoadLibrary search path.

Comment: How would an AppPath be relevant? They don't influence DLL search so far as I know. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you are correct. Answer adjusted.

Comment: Another option is to use `GetModuleFileName()` to get the full path that MY_DLL_N1.dll was loaded from, swap the filename with MY_DLL_N2.dll, and pass the new full path to `LoadLibrary()`.  Then you do not have to worry about the search path at all.